# How to check if all checkbox are unchecked?

Tags: android, xml, listview, checkbox

The question may sound tricky....

but, the thing is, I've got a custom list view with a checkbox and a textview on every row... I've used  **android:onClick="checkmethod"**  to make a process when a checkbox are checked..

here's a sample code..

```
public void checkMethod(View v) {
LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_list);
  if (check.isChecked()) {
      //My process goes here
  }else{
      //Another process comes here
  }
}
```

now, what I want to do is checking the checkboxes if their states are all unchecked... 
how can I do this? can someon please help me asap? thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the fastest and simplest approach I know about:

- Add an `private int counter` as a class member, and initialize it to 0.
- When checkbox is selected - increment counter
- When checkbox is deselected - decrement counter
- Whenever you need to check if no checkbox is checked - just check if `counter == 0`

Comment: Thanks for the logic Binyamin Sharet!! You're the best!! I really appreciate it!! THANKS AGAIN!! ahaha now I can smile!! I'm so dumb ahaha I never think of that.. ahahaha thanks, many thanks!!